Characterize the mixed strategy Bayesian Nash equilibria for this game.
A two-player game where Player 1 can choose either U or D and Player 2 can choose either L or R. Player 1 is either cooperative with probability $P$ or uncooperative with probability $1−P$. Player 1 knows his type, but Player 2 doesn’t know Player 1's type. Characterize the mixed strategy Bayesian Nash equilibria for this game.
Following is the game matrix:

I know in theory what mixed strategy BNE is, but working this one out is cumbersome since there are no dominated strategies. Can someone help, please?

Hi @ToshaniSingh. If this is a homework (or an exam) question, I would really appreciate it if you could share the solution provided by your instructor!

The answer I wrote below is based on my understanding of the theory presented in Game Theory: Analysis of Conflict by Roger Myerson. I would really appreciate it if someone who is more familiar with the technique of computing Bayesian Nash equilibria could comment below and share your thought on it! Thank you very much!

This is how I would proceed. Note that a Bayesian equilibrium of the game $\Gamma^b$ is any randomized-strategy profile $\sigma$ such that, for every player $i$ in $N$ and every type $t_i$ in $T_i$,
\begin{align*}
\sigma_i(\cdot|t_i) \in \text{argmax}_{\tau_i \in \Delta(C_i)} \sum_{t_{-i} \in T_{-i}} p_i(t_{-i}|t_i) \sum_{c\in C}\left(\prod_{j \in N-i}\sigma_j(c_j|t_j)\right)\tau_i(c_i)u_i(c,t)
\end{align*}
As for our game, we make the following definition:

$C_1 = \{x_1,y_1\}$, where $x_1$ means "up" and $y_1$ means "down".
$C_2 = \{x_2,y_2\}$, where $x_2$ means "left" and $y_2$ means "right".
$T_1 = \{1.1,1.2\}$, where 1.1 stands for player 1's type of coorperative and 1.2 stands for player 1's type of uncooperative.
$T_2 = \{2.0\}$, where 2.0 stands for player 2's only possible type.
$p_2(1.1|2.0) = p$ and $p_2(1.2|2.0) = 1-p$, where $p_2(\cdot|2.0)$ represents what player 2 would believe about player 1's types given his own type being 2.0.

So the game shall be represented in the following table:

Consider the matrix for $t_1=1.1$. Clearly, there are two pure strategy Nash equilibria:
\begin{align*}
\sigma_1(\cdot|1.1)=[x_1],\ \sigma_2=[x_2]\quad \text{and}\quad \sigma_1(\cdot|1.1)=[y_1],\ \sigma_2=[y_2],
\end{align*}
and one mixed strategy Nash equilibrium:
\begin{align*}
\sigma_1(\cdot|1.1)=\frac{1}{2}[x_1]+\frac{1}{2}[y_1]\quad \text{and}\quad \sigma_2 = \frac{1}{2}[x_2] + \frac{1}{2}[y_2].
\end{align*}
Consider the matrix for $t_1 = 1.2$. Clearly, there is only one Nash equilibrium:
\begin{align*}
\sigma_1(\cdot|1.2)=\frac{1}{2}[x_1]+\frac{1}{2}[y_1]\quad \text{and}\quad \sigma_2 = \frac{1}{2}[x_2] + \frac{1}{2}[y_2].
\end{align*}
Therefore, we have the following three cases:
Case 1:$\quad$[Mixed strategy Nash equilibria for both matrices]
Since
\begin{align*}
\begin{alignedat}{4}
       &p_2(1.1|2.0) \cdot (&&\sigma_1(x_1|1.1) \cdot \tau_2(x_2) \cdot u_1((x_1,x_2),(1.1,2.0)) &\ +\\
       &                    &&\sigma_1(y_1|1.1) \cdot \tau_2(x_2) \cdot u_1((y_1,x_2),(1.1,2.0)) &\ +\\
       &                    &&\sigma_1(x_1|1.1) \cdot \tau_2(y_2) \cdot u_1((x_1,y_2),(1.1,2.0)) &\ +\\
       &                    &&\sigma_1(y_1|1.1) \cdot \tau_2(y_2) \cdot u_1((y_1,y_2),(1.1,2.0)))&\\
    =\ &0                   &&                                                                   &
\end{alignedat}
\end{align*}
and
\begin{align*}
\begin{alignedat}{4}
       &p_2(1.2|2.0) \cdot (&&\sigma_1(x_1|1.2) \cdot \tau_2(x_2) \cdot u_1((x_1,x_2),(1.2,2.0)) &\ +\\
       &                    &&\sigma_1(y_1|1.2) \cdot \tau_2(x_2) \cdot u_1((y_1,x_2),(1.2,2.0)) &\ +\\
       &                    &&\sigma_1(x_1|1.2) \cdot \tau_2(y_2) \cdot u_1((x_1,y_2),(1.2,2.0)) &\ +\\
       &                    &&\sigma_1(y_1|1.2) \cdot \tau_2(y_2) \cdot u_1((y_1,y_2),(1.2,2.0)))&\\
    =\ &0,                  &&                                                                   &
\end{alignedat}
\end{align*}
it follows that
\begin{align*}
&\text{argmax}_{\tau_2 \in \Delta(C_2)} \sum_{t_{1} \in T_{1}} p_2(t_{1}|t_2) \sum_{c\in C}\left(\prod_{j \in \{1\}}\sigma_j(c_j|t_j)\right)\tau_2(c_2)u_2(c,t)\\
=\ &\text{argmax}_{\tau_2 \in \Delta(C_2)} 0\\
=\ &0.
\end{align*}
Thus, $\sigma_2(\cdot|2.0) = \alpha[x_2] + (1-\alpha)[y_2]$ for all $\alpha \in [0,1]$, $\sigma_1(\cdot|1.1) = \frac{1}{2}[x_1]+\frac{1}{2}[y_1]$, and $\sigma_1(\cdot|1.2) = \frac{1}{2}[x_1] + \frac{1}{2}[y_1]$ is a Bayesian equilibrium.
Case 2:$\quad$[The first pure equilibrium for matrix $\mathbf{t_1=}\ $1.1]
Since
\begin{align*}
p_2(1.1|2.0)\cdot(1\cdot\tau_2(x_2)\cdot1+0+1\cdot\tau_2(y_2)\cdot(-1)+0) = p(\tau_2(x_2)-\tau_2(y_2)),
\end{align*}
it follows that
\begin{align*}
&\text{argmax}_{\tau_2 \in \Delta(C_2)} \sum_{t_{1} \in T_{1}} p_2(t_{1}|t_2) \sum_{c\in C}\left(\prod_{j \in \{1\}}\sigma_j(c_j|t_j)\right)\tau_2(c_2)u_2(c,t)\\
=\ &\text{argmax}_{\tau_2 \in \Delta(C_2)} p\cdot(\tau_2(x_2)-\tau_2(y_2))\\
=\ &(\tau_2(x_2)=1,\tau_2(y_2)=0)\\
=\ &[x_2].
\end{align*}
Thus, $\sigma_2(\cdot|2.0)=[x_2]$, $\sigma_1(\cdot|1.1)=[x_1]$, and $\sigma_1(\cdot|1.2) = \frac{1}{2}[x_1]+\frac{1}{2}[y_1]$ is a Bayesian equilibrium.
Case 3:$\quad$[The second pure equilibrium for matrix $\mathbf{t_1=}\ $1.1]
Since
\begin{align*}
p_2(1.1|2.0)\cdot(0+1\cdot\tau_2(x_2)\cdot(-1)+0+1\cdot\tau_2(y_2)\cdot1) = p(\tau_2(y_2)-\tau_2(x_2)),
\end{align*}
it follows that
\begin{align*}
&\text{argmax}_{\tau_2 \in \Delta(C_2)} \sum_{t_{1} \in T_{1}} p_2(t_{1}|t_2) \sum_{c\in C}\left(\prod_{j \in \{1\}}\sigma_j(c_j|t_j)\right)\tau_2(c_2)u_2(c,t)\\
=\ &\text{argmax}_{\tau_2 \in \Delta(C_2)} p\cdot(\tau_2(y_2)-\tau_2(x_2))\\
=\ &(\tau_2(x_2)=0,\tau_2(y_2)=1)\\
=\ &[y_2].
\end{align*}
Thus, $\sigma_2(\cdot|2.0)=[y_2]$, $\sigma_1(\cdot|1.1)=[y_1]$, and $\sigma_1(\cdot|1.2) = \frac{1}{2}[x_1]+\frac{1}{2}[y_1]$ is a Bayesian equilibrium.
